# What software do I need to exchange Bitcoins?

Tags: linux, command-line, bitcoin

I need software to exchange Bitcoins that could run on Ubuntu desktops and server; a command-line one.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit both on the desktop and on the server.

What software can I use?

I have tried installing both [`bitcoin-qt`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592383/how-can-i-run-bitcoin-qt-on-ubuntu-14-04-amd64-the-one-from-official-ppa-keeps) and [`bitcoind`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592383/how-can-i-run-bitcoin-qt-on-ubuntu-14-04-amd64-the-one-from-official-ppa-keeps). I have tried compiling from source, [per this tutorial](http://bitzuma.com/posts/compile-bitcoin-core-from-source-on-ubuntu/). They all crash.

I figured there the official package called Bitcoin Core (of wich `bitcoin-qt` and `bitcoind` are partts) is not the only software available: [there are lots of wallets](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/bitcoin-wallets/) that allow one to manage Bitcoin wallets. What is the command-line solution that works? There is one, right? Bitcoin is the #1 cryptocurrency, and Ubuntu LTS is a popular system, after all, so there should be a command-line solution that works, right?

If I need to check out a specific another version of Bitcoin Core (e.g. an earlier one) or apply some pathes or build flags, I'm ok with that. Anything taht I can roll into a script to run in a single step is fine with me, though I prefer the most 'official' solution possible. I'm actually pretty surprised that the binaries in the official ppa's are broken.